# using jQuery within Colorbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am having some problems when trying to use jQuery from within colorbox.

When I call any jQuery from the page that calls the colorbox it works fine.

My code currently calls a colorbox with another page inside it using the following code.

```
var page1 = '/page1/page.php';

jQuery(".page1click").colorbox({opacity:0.4, rel:'nofollow', href:page1, height:'700px', width: '702px', iframe:true});
```

This all works correctly and my code is showing within the colorbox popup. Also all of my javascript code is working within this page. However when I try and use any jQuery from within the colorbox it does not work.

What i am trying to do is hide a div when it is clicked.

If anyone could help that would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether u included jquery in both the pages. This can create conflicts.

Comment: I have included jQuery in both pages now and the jQuery that i am calling from within a javascript function is working fine but when i try to use $(document).ready(function(){}); it is giving me the error  "$ is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

With plugins that create overlays, like colorbox, they take your html markup and create another element in the DOM with it. Therefore the div you are trying to hide, **might not have the same ID/class that you used to create it**.

Please inspect the element using firebug in firefox to see what ID/class your div has been assigned by the plugin when you are viewing the box created by Colorbox.